# iOS 11 only crash issue - when I tap a tab bar App is crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, ios11

I am getting following crash error when I tap a particular tab bar only from hometabviewcontroller. This Happens only in iOS 11. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
    2017-10-23 16:48:57.000890+0400 FixtrProvider[2520:910402] desc: -[UIView refreshControl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10af090d0
2017-10-23 16:48:57.001223+0400 FixtrProvider[2520:910402] name: NSInvalidArgumentException
2017-10-23 16:48:57.001308+0400 FixtrProvider[2520:910402] user info: (null)
2017-10-23 16:48:57.001441+0400 FixtrProvider[2520:910402] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView refreshControl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10af090d0'
```

Following is the whole Page of my HomeTabView Controller according to the request.

```
@interface HomeTabBarController ()
{
    ChatSocketIOClient *socket;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *onTheJobOffTheJobButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *status;
@property LocationTracker * locationTracker;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimer* locationUpdateTimer;
@end

@implementation HomeTabBarController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Crash bug fixing
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    if (!socket) {
        socket  =[ChatSocketIOClient sharedInstance];
    }
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self tabbarImages];
}

-(void)tabbarImages
{
    NSString *homeunselect;
    NSString *homeselect;
    NSString *historyunselect;
    NSString *historyselect;
    NSString *scheduleunselect;
    NSString *scheduleselect;
    NSString *earnunselect;
    NSString *earnselect;
    NSString *proilfeunselect;
    NSString *profileselect;


    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;

    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem5 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height <= 568) {
        homeunselect = @"provider_popup_home_btn";
        homeselect = @"provider_popup_home_btn_selector";

        historyunselect = @"provider_popup_history_btn";
        historyselect = @"provider_popup_history_btn_selector";

        scheduleunselect = @"provider_popup_schedule_btn";
        scheduleselect = @"provider_popup_selector_btn_selector";

        earnunselect = @"provider_popup_earnings_btn";
        earnselect = @"provider_popup_earnings_btn_selector";

        proilfeunselect = @"provider_popup_profile_btn";
        profileselect = @"provider_popup_profile_btn_selector";
    }else if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 667){
        homeunselect = @"6provider_popup_home_btn";
        homeselect = @"6provider_popup_home_btn_selector";

        historyunselect = @"6provider_popup_history_btn";
        historyselect = @"6provider_popup_history_btn_selector";

        scheduleunselect = @"6provider_popup_schedule_btn";
        scheduleselect = @"6provider_popup_selector_btn_selector";

        earnunselect = @"6provider_popup_earnings_btn";
        earnselect = @"6provider_popup_earnings_btn_selector";

        proilfeunselect = @"6provider_popup_profile_btn";
        profileselect = @"6provider_popup_profile_btn_selector";
    }else if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height >= 736){
        homeunselect = @"6pprovider_popup_home_btn";
        homeselect = @"6pprovider_popup_home_btn_selector";

        historyunselect = @"6pprovider_popup_history_btn";
        historyselect = @"6pprovider_popup_history_btn_selector";

        scheduleunselect = @"6pprovider_popup_schedule_btn";
        scheduleselect = @"6pprovider_popup_selector_btn_selector";

        earnunselect = @"6pprovider_popup_earnings_btn";
        earnselect = @"6pprovider_popup_earnings_btn_selector";

        proilfeunselect = @"6pprovider_popup_profile_btn";
        profileselect = @"6pprovider_popup_profile_btn_selector";
    }


    tabBarItem1.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:homeselect] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
    tabBarItem1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:homeunselect] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];

    tabBarItem2.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:historyselect]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
    tabBarItem2.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:historyunselect]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];

    tabBarItem3.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:scheduleselect]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
    tabBarItem3.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:scheduleunselect]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];

    tabBarItem4.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:earnselect]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
    tabBarItem4.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:earnunselect]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];

    tabBarItem5.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:profileselect]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
    tabBarItem5.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:proilfeunselect]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];

}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"OnChatController"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
}
```

This App getting crashed when I tapped tabbar-4 in iOS 11 only. I don't understand what's the wrong with my code. I didn't get any code related to refreshController either on Hometabviewcontroller or accountscontroller. but I got the following when I search entire code base.

```
    - (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

Following is the viewloads code of the particular tabview controller.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
     _paymentLogs.selected = YES;

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

   self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColorFromRGB(0XfEAA26)};
}

-(void)getFinancialData{
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow];
    [[ProgressIndicator sharedInstance] showPIOnWindow:window withMessge:NSLocalizedString(@"Loading...",@"Loading...")];
    _pastCycle = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *dict =@{
                          @"ent_sess_token": [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:KDAcheckUserSessionToken],
                          @"ent_dev_id":  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kPMDDeviceIdKey],
                          @"ent_date_time":[Helper getCurrentDateTime],
                          @"ent_pro_id": [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ProviderId"]
                          };
    NetworkHandler *handler  =[NetworkHandler sharedInstance];
    [handler composeRequestWithMethod:@"GetFinancialData"
                              paramas:dict
                         onComplition:^(BOOL succeeded, NSDictionary *response) {
                             if (succeeded) {
                                 _pastCycle = [response[@"pastCycle"] mutableCopy];
                                 _currentCycle = response[@"currentCycle"];
                                 NSLog(@"financial data %@",response);
                                 [self.currentTableView reloadData];
                                 [self.pastTableView reloadData];
                                 [[ProgressIndicator sharedInstance] hideProgressIndicator];
                             }
                         }];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(userSessionTokenExpire) name:@"HandleAcceptAndRejectFromAdmin" object:nil];

}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"HandleAcceptAndRejectFromAdmin" object:nil];

}

-(void)userSessionTokenExpire{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:KDAcheckUserSessionToken];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    ProgressIndicator *pi = [ProgressIndicator sharedInstance];
    [pi hideProgressIndicator];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                @"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    iServeSplashController *splah = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splash"];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:splah, nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}



-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    _pastCycle = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self getFinancialData];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(accountDeactivated) name:@"accountDeactivated" object:nil];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate the issue or provide some code sample

Comment: Post code of `hometabviewcontroller`

Comment: @Bearwithme code posted...

Comment: Can you show properties in `Hometabviewcontroller` and `accountscontroller` ?

Comment: It also solved by removing contentScrollView from accountsController Properties .. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can track where the `unrecognized selector sent to instance` comes from. Something in your code is calling it.

Do a text search in `hometabviewcontroller` or entire project for `refreshControl` and see where and what is calling it and make sure it's what you want.

If that does not help we need more code (preferably `hometabviewcontroller`) to help you.

Comment: I have added the required codes. Please help me. It's very hard to find the issue. It's happening only in iOS 11.